# How to center some rows in table but not others

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the code

```
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2} \\ \midrule
        should be centered &  should be centered\\
        should be centered & should be centered\\
        \\
        Should be left aligned
        & 
        Should be left aligned\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This gives me the following table

[image]

**How do I center some lines but not others?**

Comment: You already use the syntax `\multicolumn{1}{c}{column 1}`, which you can apply to other entries as well.

Comment: Please indicate whether automatic line breaking should be allowed in the centered and left-aligned cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very simple way is to repeat what you have done in the first row. Or, since there are more centered than left-aligned rows, you could also just use `\multicolumn` for the left-aligned rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2} \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{should be centered} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{should be
        centered}\\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{should be centered} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{should be
        centered}\\
        \\
        Should be left aligned
        & 
        Should be left aligned\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        column 1 & column 2 \\ \midrule
        should be centered &  should be
        centered\\
        should be centered & should be
        centered\\
        \\
        \multicolumn{1}{p{0.4\linewidth}}{Should be left aligned}
        & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{0.4\linewidth}}{Should be left aligned}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that since you're using the `p` column type for both main columns, automatic line breaking should be allowed regardless of whether the lines are left-aligned or centered. The following solution achieves this formatting goal.

Note that the `\RaggedRight` directive, which is used in the definition of the `L` column type, induces left-alignment (while still allowing hyphenation, if needed). In contrast, the basic `p` column type performs full justification, *not* left-alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e}
% define 2 column types that perform centering and left-alignment, resp.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
\newcommand\mC[2]{\multicolumn{1}{C{#1}}{#2}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{L{0.4}L{0.4}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} \\ 
      \midrule
      \mC{0.4}{Should be centered while allowing line breaks} & 
      \mC{0.4}{Should be centered while allowing line breaks}\\
      \mC{0.4}{Should be centered while allowing line breaks} & 
      \mC{0.4}{Should be centered while allowing line breaks}\\
      \\
      Should be left-aligned while allowing line breaks & 
      Should be left-aligned while allowing line breaks\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `L{0.4}L{0.4}` do?